# unable to render the data in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I have added a webpart of type app and when I try to edit the list this is what occurs:

I click on edit and I can edit the fields
when I click on stop editing this list then I got an error saying "unable to render the data", and then it stop on this state and have to back in the browser to edit.

note: I have two linked lists and the error occurs when I set the connection between the two webparts master and detail lists.

Answer (score 1):

the error appears because I deleted the field ID from the view of the detail list, I didn't  wanted this to appear in the list view but if it is not there I got the error.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer to stop it from bouncing up on the startpage multiple years after